# Inorganic foreign author books for odd electron species

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, books

I need a foreign author book which explains odd electron species in great detail ,(explaining dimerization , energetic) telling hybridization of central atom with one unpaired electron on it pls tell me the book. I need to understand this topic and I don't have any idea of foreign author books pls

Comment: What do you mean by foreign author books? Do you mean foreign language (non-English) books?

Comment: I need books name which covers the above topic ( English)

Comment: Holleman and Wiberg 2000 paged book on Inorganic Chemistry.

Comment: @M.Farooq, The OP means non-Indian books. It's a frequent irrelevant colloquialism used in India, which actually refers to *good quality books*. To the OP: using the phrase *foreign author books* makes no sense in an international community.

Comment: I had guessed that from OPs previous and current post ithat he is implying foreign books=good quality books. Holleman & Wiberg is originally written in German but current editions are in English as well. I have not seen a thicker single volume book on Inorganic Chemistry. It should be available in a good university library in India and/or from Amazon. Some scammer on Amazon is selling it for $5000. Amazing! The actual price should be much much lower.